# Ghidra scripting get information from decompile window

Tags: assembly, c, ghidra

I am using Ghidra and when clicking for example in the decompile window on a specific raw, it change the cursor in the assembly window to the exact location in the assembly. Is there any option to do this using Ghidra scripting ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example for what you mean ? I need to decompile the code using "getDecompiledFunction" and then i can use this function "getReferencesFrom" ?

Comment: @R4444 - forgot to tag you

Comment: Do you mean you have a list of addresses that you want to change the location in the assembly (listing) window to? If so, you can just use the GhidraScript method `setCurrentLocation`

Comment: @DanielDan You could write a comment under the specific answer (R4444's one, in this case), to ask follow up questions on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want instruction access references to a particular variable, then first define the reference manager:

```
refmanager = program.referenceManager
```

Then lets say you get all the local variables of a particular function - using -

```
vars = function.getLocalVariables()
```

You can get references to a particular variable:

```
for var in vars:
    for ref in refmanager.getReferencesTo(var):
        print(ref)
```

In this case `ref` will be of type `Reference`. The you can get particular references using [this](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/model/symbol/Reference.html) api. Also check [this](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/model/symbol/ReferenceManager.html#getReferencesTo(ghidra.program.model.listing.Variable)) for other options.